# Dictionary Keys in Alphabetical Order with multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to print a dictionary with the keys being in alphabetical order, but echo key has multiple values.

I have already tried:

```
for name, scores in sorted(class1.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
```

above the

```
for k, v in class1.items():
    print("{name} : {score}".format(name=k, score=v[-3:]))
```

But that didn't make any change to the result of my code.

UPDATE

I fixed it now, I went to school and I realised that I just had to do this:

```
for k, v in sorted(class1.items()):
    print("{name} : {score}".format(name=k, score=v[-3:]))
```

Comment: "*echo key*"? Do you mean "each key"?

Comment: Also, please produce a short, self-contained program that demonstrates the error you are having.  In particular, please include the actual and expected output of your program. Please read [mcve] for more information.

Comment: What is your input, your output and what output do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
for k in sorted(class1.keys()):
    print("{name} : {score}".format(name=k, score=class1[k][-3:]))
```